# How to process JSON documents (from MongoDB) and write to HBase in Structured Streaming?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting mongoDB document, then after processing I want to store it into Hbase using Bson.Document library

Changing streaming method from spark kafkastreaming to structured streaming
So earlier method using kafkaUtils was producing Dstream[Document]

In structured streaming I am getting Dataset[Document]

```
scala> val stream = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","brokerList").option("subscribe", s"topic_name").load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
stream: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> val strming_doc = stream.map(record => record.getAs[String]("value")
scala> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]
```

for further processes I need to get document from the dataset

```
scala> val stream = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","brokerList").option("subscribe", s"topic_name").load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
stream: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> val strming_doc = stream.map(record => record.getAs[String]("value")
scala> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]
```

I need to get document from the dataset, its basically to get data from mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need `foreach` or `foreachBatch` operators to write a result of the streaming query to HBase. Please consult [Using Foreach and ForeachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) in the official documentation.